# How to convert date in number to words

Tags: r

I expanded a timestamp in to different columns, then I used this code to show days of the week.

```
df$day_of_week <- ordered(df$day_of_week, 
    levels=c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
```

I used the same code to show month in words but the result was NA.

What's the best way to do this? Please help

```
df$month <- ordered(df$month,
    levels=c("January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",,,,,,,,,,,,,)
```

I want my date column to display names of the month rather the number

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data with `dput(head(df))` or just `dput(head(df$month))`. It could be due to several things.

Comment: Also you can use the built-in  `month.name` if you don't feel like typing out all the months.

Comment: I tried the month.name but the result is "could not find function"

Answer (score 1):

you could use base r `months` function or the `lubridate` package

```
> timestamps<-c(Sys.time(),Sys.time()-10^10,Sys.time()-10^8)
> ## base R
> months(timestamps)
[1] "December" "February" "October" 
> ## lubridate
> library(lubridate)
> timestamps|>month(label = TRUE)
[1] Dec Feb Oct
12 Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun < ... < Dec
> timestamps|>weekdays()
[1] "Thursday" "Tuesday"  "Tuesday"
```